# Joining CSVs in Bash where the key in one table is used multiple times

Tags: bash, csv, join, merge

I have a csv where an identifier appears multiple times, and another csv with information about that identifier. I'd like to append the columns in the 2nd csv to the first one for each row.

```
data1.csv
+---+---------------------+--------+
| ID| DATE                | AMOUNT |
+---+---------------------+--------+
| 1 | 2019-09-08 00:00:00 |   3000 |
| 1 | 2019-10-08 00:00:00 |   1500 |
| 1 | 2019-11-20 00:00:00 |   1560 |
| 2 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+------+

data2.csv
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | Location  | 
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
|  1 | J. Smith |  32 | New York  |
|  2 | A. Jones |  25 | Chicago   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+
```

I would like to create

```
+---+---------------------+--------+----------+-----+-----------+
| ID| DATE                | AMOUNT | NAME     | AGE | Location  | 
+---+---------------------+--------+----------+-----+-----------+
| 1 | 2019-09-08 00:00:00 |   3000 | J. Smith |  32 | New York  |
| 1 | 2019-10-08 00:00:00 |   1500 | J. Smith |  32 | New York  |
| 1 | 2019-11-20 00:00:00 |   1560 | J. Smith |  32 | New York  |
| 2 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |   2060 | A. Jones |  25 | Chicago   |
+-----+---------------------+------+----------+-----+-----------+
```

I'm trying to do this in native bash if it all possible - some users will be using Cygwin in Windows and it's a whole mess to try to run Python if they don't have it set up correctly. Normally, I'd just use Pandas.

So far, everything I've been able to find expects that the CSVs can be sorted and each one matched. I can imagine creating a loop that looks up each ID in data1 and looks for it in data2, then combines them via awk, but this dataset will have a lot of repeats, and it seems like that would be a really inefficient way to go about it.

It seems like there should be an existing way to do a left join on a repeatable key, but I'm not seeing anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a `join` utility in *nix land. You do need to have yoru data sorted by the key you want to join, but that shouldn't be a big deal. You can post process your output back to some other sorting if you need that instead. Search here for `[linux] [sort] [join]` and it should be easy. I'd recommend working with the sample data you have posted and just let the output come to the terminal. That will be the fastest way to debug any issues. Once you feel you understand how it works, then try larger files and save the output via `...> joinedOutput.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: Do your actual files include those ascii art tables? They're not CSV if so and dealing with the noise is a lot more work...

Comment: They're normal csv files. I stole the ascii art from another post here on SQL tables because I thought it'd be easier to see than a bunch of columns of csv

Answer (score 2):

A shell solution would be slow for large set of data/files, but here it is.

data1.csv and it's content

```
ID,DATE,AMOUNT
1,2019-09-08 00:00:00,3000
1,2019-10-08 00:00:00,1500
1,2019-11-20 00:00:00,1560
2,2008-05-20 00:00:00,2060
```

data2.csv and it's content

```
ID,NAME,AGE,Location
1,J. Smith,32,New York
2,A. Jones,25,Chicago
```

---

The script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS= read -r data1_head < data1.csv
IFS= read -r data2_head < data2.csv
printf '%s,%s\n' "$data1_head" "${data2_head#*,}"

while IFS= read -ru8 data1; do
  while IFS= read -ru9 data2; do
    if [[ "${data1%%,*}" == "${data2%%,*}" ]]; then
      printf '%s,%s\n' "$data1" "${data2#*,}"
    fi
  done 9< <(tail -n+2 data2.csv)
done 8< <(tail -n+2 data1.csv)
```

---

The output

```
ID,DATE,AMOUNT,NAME,AGE,Location
1,2019-09-08 00:00:00,3000,J. Smith,32,New York
1,2019-10-08 00:00:00,1500,J. Smith,32,New York
1,2019-11-20 00:00:00,1560,J. Smith,32,New York
2,2008-05-20 00:00:00,2060,A. Jones,25,Chicago
```

---

If `ed` is available/acceptable, assumes that both csv files are in the same directory as the script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ed -s data1.csv <<-'EOF'
    1r data2.csv
    2s/^ID//
    1,2j
    g/^1,[[:digit:]]/ /^1,[[:alpha:]]/t.
    g/^2,[[:digit:]]/ /^2,[[:alpha:]]/t.
    2,3d
    g/^[[:digit:]]/+1s/^[[:digit:]]//
    g/^[[:digit:]]/;/^,.*/j
    ,p
    Q
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about it if you have 2 csv files, otherwise it may turn out to be tricky. Ofcourse, these solutions would include awk, sort etc.

However, The most effective and simplest way would be to use the csvkit. First install csvkit : `sudo pip install csvkit` (you would need to install python3 and python3-pip)

There are various tools in the suite, like csvcut, csvlook which allows to look and cut the columns you are interested in. But for your case `csvjoin` is an effective tool.

`csvjoin -c 1 file1.csv file2.csv` This command joins the two files on column 1.

Here is more information about this:
https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.5/scripts/csvjoin.html

here is my answer on a slightly different question, you may find useful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63238703/13876104